# Is there a way to support state-list animation on old Androids?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable

At API Level 11 Android has started support new `selector` attribute, `android:exitFadeDuration`.

This attribute allows you to change the states with smooth animation between them.
Is there a way to stimulate the effect of this attribute on old Androids? For example, via writing custom Drawable or using Drawable transitions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880086/android-animate-background-image

Comment: @user1337 without program code injections in view. For example, I want to animate Action Bar background elements.